# Cycle detected when computing super predicates in trait definitions. Rust compile-time error

Tags: rust

Consider the two traits

```rust
trait Super<T: ?Sized> {
    fn test(&self, p: Box<T>) -> Box<T>; // line not necessary to trigger the compilation error
}
trait Child: Super<dyn Child> {}
```

which yields the following at compile-time:

```
error[E0391]: cycle detected when computing the super predicates of `Child`
   --> src/main.rs:103:1
    |
    | trait Child: Super<dyn Child> {}
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: ...which requires computing the super traits of `Child`...
   --> src/main.rs:103:1
    |
    | trait Child: Super<dyn Child> {}
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: ...which again requires computing the super predicates of `Child`, completing the cycle
note: cycle used when collecting item types in top-level module
   --> src/main.rs:103:1
    |
    | trait Child: Super<dyn Child> {}
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When monomorphizing functions, it was my understanding, that the generics basically get filled in at compile time. This hopefully enabling all sorts of neat optimizations. So I expected something similar to happen for traits, but

```rust
trait Super {
    fn test(&self, p: Box<dyn Child>) -> Box<dyn Child>;
}
trait Child: Super {}
```

actually compiles. So not self-referential after all?

What is going on here? I know, that this error message has [caused confusion in the past](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62581), but I don't think that applies here. I assume the compiler is being conservative and we could have gotten up to some shenanigans in `Super`?

Comment: It might help if you told us what concrete problem you're trying to solve with this design. It seems like you're trying to apply the C++ [CRTP pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to Rust. Normally it's not needed because Rust supports supplying a "blanket implementation" of a trait that does most of what you'd use CRTP in C++ for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This I believe is mainly a trait a coherence issue. After monomorphizing the generics, your traits look like this:

```rust
trait Super<dyn Child> {
    fn test(&self, p: Box<dyn Child>) -> Box<dyn Child>; 
}
trait Child: Super<dyn Child> {}
```

What happens is when rustc tries to prove the validity of `Super<dyn Child>` it finds itself needing to evaluate the statement  `Super<dyn Child>` is valid if and only if `Super<dyn Child>` is valid, which is an error. On the other hand, in your other example, `Child` is valid if there exists a valid trait `Super` with no generic parameters. Because `Super` has no super traits it is well-formed, meaning both `Child` and `Super` are valid. The object safety of `Child` then follows a similar line of reasoning.

I was able to rewrite the `Child` trait in a way that does work with the given `Super` trait. However, before you use it, you should spend some time thinking about other ways to structure your code.

```rust
trait Super<T: ?Sized> {
    fn test(&self, p: Box<T>) -> Box<T>;
}
trait Inner {}
trait Marker: Super<dyn Inner> {}
trait Child: Marker {}

impl<T: Super<dyn Inner>> Marker for T {}

impl<T: Super<dyn Child>> Super<dyn Inner> for T {
    fn test(&self, _p: Box<dyn Inner>) -> Box<dyn Inner> {
        unreachable!()
    }
}
```

The idea here is to use a couple of marker traits for the bounds, and use blanket impls to break the cyclical dependency.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=05430eb787d811db8a9c25e9d19e7d39)

Answer (score 0):

I love the trick @Aiden4 showed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69442930/5182723). Breaking the cycle basically comes down to having an intermediate `Marker` type and the best would be some never type like empty enum.

You can still sidestep this by implementing `Super<Marker>` directly on your type, however stupid it may be. To guard against that `Marker` trait should be private which would at least prevent other crates from implementing `Super<Marker>` on their types

If I may be so bold, I'd like to suggest the following improvement:

```rs
    mod private {
        pub enum Marker {}
    }

    trait Super<T: ?Sized> {
        fn test(&self, p: Box<T>) -> Box<T>;
    }

    trait Child: Super<private::Marker> {}
    impl<T: Super<dyn Child>> Super<private::Marker> for T {
        // This method literally cannot be called because `Marker` cannot be constructed
        fn test(&self, _p: Box<private::Marker>) -> Box<private::Marker> {
            unreachable!()
        }
    }
```

The only downside to this pattern is that it's not obvious from `Child` trait declaration that `Super<dyn Child>` is it's supertrait

---

Another solution might be to move the type parameter from the trait declaration into method like this:

```rs
    trait Super {
        fn test<T: ?Sized>(&self, p: Box<T>) -> Box<T>;
    }

    trait Child: Super {}
```